# JavaScript to open a new page when clicking on a link located in another part of the page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, hyperlink, new-window

I have a SharePoint `.aspx` page, a `webpart` which contains a link that opens a page, and I can't change the webpart. How can I add `JavaScript` that opens a page in a new window?

This code helps, but I need to locate the webpart link, and handle a click on the link by opening a new page:

```
<a href="http://URL" target="_blank">LINK</a>
```

Comment: [easy enough to find out](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=js%20open%20new%20window%20from%20link)

Comment: Did you mean to include an actual URL at "LINK"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Comment: <a href="#" target="_blank"/>  OR in JS: window.open(url,"_blank");

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript, you need to first obtain a reference to the link's `<a>` element. You can do this through a number of different methods, such as `document.querySelector()` or `document.getElementById()`.

Once you have a reference to the element, you can add the `target="_blank"` attribute by calling `element.setAttribute("target","_blank")` (where `element` is the variable containing the reference to the `<a>` element.

The exact code needed depends on the HTML in the web part that contains the link, since that will determine how you can get a reference to the element.